# How many characters are there from the 3 Salvage Droid planets each and the Shipwreck

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I've gotten 3 characters from Endor and 2 from Kashyyyk so far. I would like to know how many characters there are from the 3 Salvage Droid planets (Endor, Kashyyyk and Csilla) and also the Shipwreck so I would know when to stop spending bux on those planets.

Please contribute if you gotten different characters for your game from the other contributors.

**Kashyyyk** (From top to bottom, and then left to right: Chuundar, Quagga)
[image: Wookies]

**Endor** (Teebo, Teek and Willy)
[image: Ewoks]

**Csilla**
None at the moment.

**Shipwreck**
None at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Now I've finally managed to get them all, so I can confirm the remaining ones. This is the final list:

- Kashyyyk: Chuundar, Freyyr, Quagga, Salporin, Tarfful.
- Endor: Deej, Logray, Shodu, Teebo, Teek, Weechee, Willy.
- Csilla: Baldarek, Sev'eere'nuruodo, Sev'rance-Tann, Shaneeka, Spiker.
- Shipwreck: 3B6-RA-7, FA-4 Pilot Droid, GNK, K3-P0, R9.

By character:

- Fist row: 3B6-RA-7 (Shipwreck), Baldarek (Csilla), Chuundar (Kashyyyk).
- Second row: Deej (Endor), FA-4 Pilot Droid (Shipwreck), Freyyr (Kashyyyk).
- Third row: GNK (Shipwreck), K3-P0 (Shipwreck), Logray (Endor).
  [image: List part 1]
- Fourth row: Quagga (Kashyyyk), R9 (Shipwreck), Salporin (Kashyyyk).
- Fifth row: Sev'eere'nuruodo (Csilla), Sev'rance-Tann (Csilla), Shaneeka (Csilla).
- Sixth row: Shodu (Endor), Spiker (Csilla), Tarfful (Kashyyyk).
  [image: List part 2]
- Seventh row: Teebo (Endor), Teek (Endor), Weechee (Endor).
- Eighth row: Willy (Endor).
  [image: List part 3]

Comment: I got Weechee from Endor so I can confirm that one.